# I am on the filters-blur problem of pset 4 in CS50. The image blurs but the values of each RGB color are slightly off and I cannot understand why

Tags: filter, cs50, blur, edges

## SOLVED:

I had to make a copy of the image in order to use original values of the image. Before using the copy, every `image[i][j]` that was blurred previously was then used in the calculations of other pixel blurrings, which ultimately lead to skewed results.

Copying of image:

```
RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];  

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
{     
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)     
    {         
        image_copy[i][j] = image[i][j];     
    } 
}
```

I then replaced every version of a modified `image[i][j]` with `image_copy[i][j]`.

## ***Problem Purpose:***

The purpose of the problem is to blur a bmp image. We take from a photo a single pixel that has three numerical color values--red, green, blue (RGB)--and we calculate the changes to those values based on all of the pixel's neighboring pixels' RGB values.

All of the information regarding the problem can be found here: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/

## ***My Issue:***

I do not understand why I am returning average RGB values that are ~20 values off (in the case of getting the middle pixels) and ~10 values off (in getting the edge pixels) of the values I should be getting according to the tests. However, the corner  cases do seem to work perfectly according to the tests (see images below):

**Visualization of pixel grid for middle pixel where `image[i][j]` is the square at the center (in blue):**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqZ7e.png

**Visualization of pixel grid for edge pixel where `image[i][j]` is the middle *reddest* square in the farthest right column:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1oBY.png

**Test results:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A6Jh.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKnAs.png

I am *not* looking for an explicit solution to this problem, but a hint in the right direction would be nice!

### **Here is my code:**

````
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // Declare averages for each color to give the pixel-to-be-blurred
    float red_average, green_average, blue_average;

    // For a row in the image.
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // For the column in the given row.
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Copy each pixel into a new pixel so you can name it something more human-readable.
            // You can then take the RGB values from the pixels to calculate the averages of each RGB value in each pixel.
            // Then you can apply those values to the original pixel (image[i][j]) we want to blur.

            RGBTRIPLE left_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE right_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE top_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE top_right_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE top_left_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE bottom_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE bottom_right_pixel;
            RGBTRIPLE bottom_left_pixel;

            // Now we calculate the average of each pixel in the photo and all of the pixels next to it
            // In the case that:

            // The pixel is surrounded on all sides.
            if (i != 0 && i != height - 1 && j != 0 && j != width - 1)
            {
                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_right_pixel = image[i - 1][j + 1];
                top_left_pixel = image[i - 1][j - 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_right_pixel = image[i + 1][j + 1];
                bottom_left_pixel = image[i + 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value in all pixels surrounding the initial pixel, and the pixel itself,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed
                            + top_right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_left_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtRed
                            + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtRed) / 9.0;
                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen
                                + top_right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_left_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen
                                + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtGreen) / 9.0;
                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue
                                + top_right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_left_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtBlue
                                + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 9.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the top-left corner of the image.
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_right_pixel = image[i + 1][j + 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the right, below, and bottom-right, including the initial pixel,
                // We need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtRed) / 4.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtGreen)
                                / 4.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 4.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the bottom-left corner of the image.
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == 0)
            {
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_right_pixel = image[i - 1][j + 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the right, top, and top-right, including the initial pixel,
                // We need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed + top_right_pixel.rgbtRed) / 4.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_right_pixel.rgbtGreen)
                                / 4.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_right_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 4.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
             // The pixel is in the top-right corner of the image.
            else if (i == 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_left_pixel = image[i + 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the left, below, and bottom-left, including the initial pixel,
                // We need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtRed) / 4.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtGreen)
                                / 4.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 4.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the bottom-right corner of the image.
            else if (i == height - 1 && j == width - 1)
            {

                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_left_pixel = image[i - 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the left, above, and top-left, including the initial pixel,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed + top_left_pixel.rgbtRed) / 4.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_left_pixel.rgbtGreen)
                                / 4.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_left_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 4.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the last row of the image, surrounded in all directions except for beneath it.
            else if (i == height - 1 && j != width - 1 && j != 0)
            {

                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_right_pixel = image[i - 1][j + 1];
                top_left_pixel = image[i - 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the left, right, above, top-left, and top-right including the initial pixel,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed
                              + top_left_pixel.rgbtRed + top_right_pixel.rgbtRed) / 6.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen
                              + top_left_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_right_pixel.rgbtGreen) / 6.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue
                              + top_left_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_right_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 6.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the first row of the image, surrounded in all directions except for above it.
            else if (i == 0 && j != width - 1 && j != 0)
            {
                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_right_pixel = image[i + 1][j + 1];
                bottom_left_pixel = image[i + 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the left, right, above, top-left, and top-right including the initial pixel,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed
                            + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtRed) / 6.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen
                              + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtGreen) / 6.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue
                              + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 6.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the far-right column of the image, surrounded in all directions except for to the right of it.
            else if (i != height - 1 && i != 0 && j == width - 1)
            {
                left_pixel = image[i][j - 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_left_pixel = image[i - 1][j - 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_left_pixel = image[i + 1][j - 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the left, above, below, top-left, and bottom-left including the initial pixel,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + left_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed
                              + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtRed + top_left_pixel.rgbtRed) / 6.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + left_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen
                              + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_left_pixel.rgbtGreen) / 6.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + left_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue
                              + bottom_left_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_left_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 6.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }
            // The pixel is in the far-left column of the image, surrounded in all directions except for to the left of it.
            else if (i != height - 1 && i != 0 && j == 0)
            {
                right_pixel = image[i][j + 1];
                top_pixel = image[i - 1][j];
                top_right_pixel = image[i - 1][j + 1];
                bottom_pixel = image[i + 1][j];
                bottom_right_pixel = image[i + 1][j + 1];

                // For each RGB value for the pixels to the right, above, below, top-right, and bottom-right including the initial pixel,
                // we need to get the average for this pixel:

                // Red:
                red_average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_pixel.rgbtRed + bottom_pixel.rgbtRed
                              + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtRed + top_right_pixel.rgbtRed) / 6.0;

                // Green:
                green_average = (image[i][j].rgbtGreen + right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_pixel.rgbtGreen + bottom_pixel.rgbtGreen
                              + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtGreen + top_right_pixel.rgbtGreen) / 6.0;

                // Blue:
                blue_average = (image[i][j].rgbtBlue + right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_pixel.rgbtBlue + bottom_pixel.rgbtBlue
                              + bottom_right_pixel.rgbtBlue + top_right_pixel.rgbtBlue) / 6.0;

                // Give each average to the original pixel's RGB values
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_average);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_average);
            }

        }
    }

    return;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just worked through this myself and wanted to share an idea on how to optimize a tiny bit.

I don't think you need to start by totally copying the image. You can just create the "image_copy" with:

```
RGBTRIPLE image_copy[height][width];
```

and then start filling that in while you calculate the blur value of each pixel in "image".

So, only a minor optimization, but you save yourself the initial "copying" of the image.